# IOException while trying to save output from ObjectInputStream to a file

Tags: java, file, stream, ioexception

I am new to the concept of working with streams and with files in Java.

I'm writing a piece of code, I have a very simple server that is listening for an incoming file.

Then I have a handler that deals with the incoming file.

Now, here is the code (stripped of try/catch blocks)

```
ObjectInputStream in;

in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
        clientSocket.getInputStream()));

File f = new File(fileName);
int byteCount = in.readInt();
byte[] fileArray = (byte[]) in.readObject();
Files.write(f.toPath(), fileArray);
```

There comes an `IOException` when the program hits the ``byte[] fileArray = (byte[]) in.readObject();`line. And - to be sure, the`int byteCount` shows the correct number of bytes, the filename is also correct...

Stacktrace looks like this:

```
java.io.OptionalDataException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1304)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at com.fileservice.util.ClientHandlerRunnable.run(ClientHandlerRunnable.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Code of the client sending the file:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket(data.getIp(), data.getTcpPort());
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    // OutputStream os = null;

    // send file
    File myFile = new File(data.getFileName());
    String test = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
    fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    os.flush();
    System.out.println("Sending " + data.getFileName() + "("
            + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
    if (os != null) {
        os.writeInt(mybytearray.length);
        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
    if (bis != null) {
        bis.close();
    }
    if (os != null) {
        os.close();
    }
    if (socket != null) {
        socket.close();

    }
```

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception? What is the code of the client sending the "file"? What's the point of sending/reading the byteCount, since it isn't used at all?

Comment: Added this information.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending raw bytes, and you're reading an object. That can't work. If you read an object, then the sender must have written an object (with `writeObject()`). If the sender writes bytes, then you must read bytes (with `read()`).

Note that your file reading section is wrong as well. `read()` gives no guarantee that it will read the number of bytes you ask it to read. You MUST use a loop to read everything. Or you can simply use [`Files.readAllBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-), which will correctly read all the bytes from the file for you.